# Why foreach loop is not working in same method in Laravel where if condition has file?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-9

Why is the foreach loop not working in the same method in Laravel if the condition has a file? But when I remove the if condition, then the foreach is working. Otherwise, only the file is saved.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{

    $userBasic = new UserBasic();
    $userBasic->userId = $request->userId;
    $userBasic->phone = $request->phone;
    $userBasic->fullName = $request->fullName;
    $userBasic->dob = $request->dob;
    $userBasic->country = $request->country;

    if ($request->hasFile('profileImg')) {
        $img = $request->file('profileImg');
        $imgName = time() . rand() . '.' . $img->extension();
        $img->move(public_path('assets/img'), $imgName);
        $profileImg = 'assets/img/' . $imgName;
        $userBasic->profileImg = $profileImg;
    }
    $userBasic->status = $request->has('status');
    $userBasic->save();

    foreach ($request->medias as $media ) {
        $userSml = new UserSocialMediaLink();
        $userSml->userId = $request->userId;
        $userSml->mediaName = $media['name'];
        $userSml->mediaLink = $media['link'];
        $userSml->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it throwing error inside the if condition? Is $userBasic->save working?

Comment: yes, it is working.

Comment: there is no error inside the if condition.

Comment: are you sure ``$request->medias`` has a value?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. and it is working when I remove the if condition.

Comment: try and return the request before entering the ```foreach``` statement and after executing the ```if``` statement

Comment: Check error logs in case there's any sort of error happening within the if condition

Comment: @YasserSebai I had already tried it, but it isn't working....

Comment: @apokryfos no error found...